# Why are you allowed to supply decimal values into a byte type?

Tags: c#

Say you have a byte variable, and you assign it the decimal value of 102. 
    (byte myByteVariable = 102;)
Why is that possible? Shouldn't you have to provide an actual 8 bit value instead to avoid confusion? And how do I set a byte value  by supplying bits instead?

Comment: `102` is an integer, not a decimal.  A decimal would be `102M`, and the value `102.0` would be a double.

Comment: `102` (base 10 "decimal" as opposed to "binary" or "hexadecimal") is an 8 bit value. There's no confusion. There are no binary literals in C#.

Comment: Because the compiler lets you type decimal numbers, it is friendly that way.  102 easily fits in a byte, it only requires 7 bits to get encoded.

Comment: @MattJohnson I mean decimal as in a base ten number.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can use hexadecimal too:  `byte myByteVariable = 0x66;`.

Comment: try `byte x = 102M;` and you will see its not possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491550/converting-from-string-bits-to-byte-or-hex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And how do I set a byte value by supplying bits instead?

If you are setting the byte value explicitly, you can do so using the prefix `0x` to indicate that you are doing so in hexadecimal, as an encoding for groups of 4 bits.  E.g. the hex value of decimal `102` is `0x66`, which is equivalent to `0110 0110`.

But for supplying bits directly, Marc Gravell provides an option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/594725/4267590) for converting from binary to int using the Convert class, and similarly you can convert the string representation of a binary value into a byte using the [Convert.ToByte method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k) as:

`byte b = Convert.ToByte("01100110", 2);`

Comment: Nice solution, I didn't know about ToByte

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert), "A conversion method exists to convert every base type to every other base type." Not all conversions are supported though and some attempts will throw exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

`byte` is a decimal type which represents a decimal number, it doesn't represent a bit field. So `102` is a normal value for it, because it's in the range of `byte` values (which is [0;255]). If you want to manipulate the bits, consider using `BitArray` or `BitVector32`.

Answer (score 1):

A `byte` can store 8 bits (that is values from 0 to 255). A `short` stores 16 bits, an `int` 32, etc. Each integer type in C# simply allows the storage of a wider range of numbers. C# allows you to assign a whole number to any of these types.

In order to set each bit individually, you will need to use [bitwise operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).

I actually wrote a [library](https://github.com/Cyral/BooleanByte/blob/master/Source/BooleanByte.cs) a while ago to handle this, allowing you to set each bit of the byte using `data[x]`. It is very similar to the [`BitArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class (which I'm not sure if I knew about when I made it)

The main idea of it is:

```
private byte data;

public void SetBit(int index, bool value)
{
    if (value)
        data = (byte)(data | (1 << index));
    else
        data = (byte)(data & ~(1 << index));
}

public bool GetBit(int index)
{
    return ((data & (1 << index)) != 0);
}
```

Comment: So setting bytes by using base 10 numerals is to maintain consistency?